# How to add AdMob to Libgdx in 2018?

Tags: libgdx, android, google-play-services, admob

I found this article here: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Admob-in-libgdx
But it's from September 2017, and since then Android and Android Studio have been updated. How can I add AdMob to my LibGdx game currently in 2018?